# How to click to specific coordinate of a page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click a link in a page with Selenium-webdriver , but i can't access the element using the value of `href` like below:

```
var link = WebDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@href='example.html']"));
```

because elements in the page is in a frame and in the source of another page. So I need to click to a specific coordinate where the link is. How can I make it by using selenium webdriver.

Comment: I tried it like that but didn't make:                                                                                                                        Actions clicker = new Actions(WebDriver);

 clicker.MoveToElement(WebElement, 200, 200);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you need to be able to do is switch to a different frame then look in that frame for the element you want rather than using co-ordinates. the problem with co-ordinates is that if you run it on a different machine the co-ordinates could be different.

```
IWebElement frame = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("xxx"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
```

then search for your element as normal. then once you are done call

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

and you will be back to the original page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that through the Actions class.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);       
builder.MoveByOffset(x, y).Click().Perform();
```

Or alternatively via `JavascriptExecutor`, just pass to it JS code needed to move to the link and click it.

Comment: Is there any tool or way to handle x and y values(coordinate any point of a web page)?